# hidden text is hidden and will not be displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my coding for creating tabs. In each i have one drop down when i select the value india in each tabs in the hidden textbox should display on the particular tab means if i select the value india in tab1 dropdown hidden textbox should not display tab2 and tab3 and i need to change w3-border red to #00a8a8 color

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {

  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("sendingType");

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(
      " w3-border-red", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-red";
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ddlPassport").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
      $("#dvPassport").show();
    } else {
      $("#dvPassport").hide();
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ddlPassport1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
      $("#dvPassport").show();
    } else {
      $("#dvPassport").hide();
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ddlPassport2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
      $("#dvPassport").show();
    } else {
      $("#dvPassport").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.sendingType {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="w3-container">

  <h2>Tabs in a Grid</h2>

  <div class="w3-row">
    <a href="#" onclick="openCity(event, 't1');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">tab1

      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="openCity(event, 't2');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">tab2</div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="openCity(event, 't3');">
      <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">tab3</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div id="t1" class="w3-container sendingType">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">dropdown</label>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select name="country" class="form-control" id="ddlPassport">
          <option value="">Select a country</option>
          <option value="Y">india</option>
          <option value="N">america</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Text box</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>



  <div id="t2" class="w3-container sendingType">


    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">dropdown</label>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select name="country" class="form-control" id="ddlPassport1">
          <option value="">Select a country</option>
          <option value="Y">india</option>
          <option value="N">america</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dvPassport1" style="display: none">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Text box</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div id="t3" class="w3-container sendingType">


    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">dropdown</label>

      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select name="country" class="form-control" id="ddlPassport2">
          <option value="">Select a country</option>
          <option value="Y">india</option>
          <option value="N">america</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dvPassport2" style="display: none">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Text box</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: kindly change the title `Hidden text box is not displaying in each tabs` is not a good one. **hidden text is hidden and will not be displayed**

Comment: Really? `$(this).val()`? jQuery has eaten out your brains, you don't even know about `this.value`, do you? Web development is doomed.

Comment: @Azamantes what is wrong with `$(this).val()`

Comment: Everything is wrong with it. Calling 2 functions instead of simply accessing the `value` property via `this.value`. Why on earth would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same hidden textbox ID every time. Us the respective textbox id. Also you don't need to use ready function every time. You can use once and add all the other function in it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$("#ddlPassport").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
      $("#dvPassport").show();
    } else {
      $("#dvPassport").hide();
    }
  });
});


  $("#ddlPassport1").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
      $("#dvPassport1").show();
    } else {
      $("#dvPassport1").hide();
    }
  });


  $("#ddlPassport2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
      $("#dvPassport2").show();
    } else {
      $("#dvPassport3").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Before am getting hidden textbox in tab1 now even that also not display with your jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openCity(evt, cityName) {

var i, x, tablinks;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("sendingType");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(
    " w3-border-red", "");
}
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.firstElementChild.className += " w3-border-red";
}


$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ddlPassport").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
    $("#dvPassport").show();
  } else {
    $("#dvPassport").hide();
  }
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ddlPassport1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
    $("#dvPassport1").show();
  } else {
    $("#dvPassport1").hide();
  }
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ddlPassport2").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "Y") {
    $("#dvPassport2").show();
  } else {
    $("#dvPassport2").hide();
  }
});
});


</script>
<style>
.sendingType {
display: none;
</style>
<body class="w3-container">

<h2>Tabs in a Grid</h2>

<div class="w3-row">
  <a href="#" onclick="openCity(event, 't1');">
    <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">tab1

    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" onclick="openCity(event, 't2');">
    <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">tab2</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" onclick="openCity(event, 't3');">
    <div class="w3-third tablink w3-bottombar w3-hover-light-grey w3-padding">tab3</div>
  </a>
</div>
<br>

<div id="t1" class="w3-container sendingType">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">dropdown1</label>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <select name="country" class="form-control" id="ddlPassport">
        <option value="">Select a country</option>
        <option value="Y">india</option>
        <option value="N">america</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Text box1</label>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>



<div id="t2" class="w3-container sendingType">


  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">dropdown2</label>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <select name="country" class="form-control" id="ddlPassport1">
        <option value="">Select a country</option>
        <option value="Y">india</option>
        <option value="N">america</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="dvPassport1" style="display: none">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Text box2</label>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>

<div id="t3" class="w3-container sendingType">


  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">dropdown3</label>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <select name="country" class="form-control" id="ddlPassport2">
        <option value="">Select a country</option>
        <option value="Y">india</option>
        <option value="N">america</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="dvPassport2" style="display: none">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-1 control-label">Text box3</label>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
```